# not able to click the login button through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

please create a selenium code for us where i am not able to hit the Login Button. see my code below and do the correction :

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("Log In")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("submit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sbt-btn-wrap relative .submit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("formButton")).click();
```

Comment: pls share the HTML or the URL of the application

Comment: See the inspect html code as well:

Comment: <input class="formButton" type="submit" onclick="form.submit();this.disabled=true;document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'; this.className='formButton-disabled';" value="Log In">

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.className("formButton")).click();` this seem to be ok. Do you get any exception?

Comment: Now it's worked fine , thanks guy's

Comment: Hi guy's pne more help required now i want to click Lock and Edit button .please see the inspect code and share your knowledge to solve my issue        .                                                   <input name="save" type="button" value="Lock &amp; Edit" onclick="disableButtons();doChangeCenter('/MakeChangesAction');" class="formButton">

Comment: @Shank087, please help on these above HTML code , now i am not able to click Lock & Edit Button                                                                                         <input name="save" type="button" value="Lock &amp; Edit" onclick="disableButtons();doChangeCenter('/MakeChangesAction‌​');" class="formButton"> –

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("save")).click(); did not work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this below xpath.

**Explanation:** User `value` attribute of `input` tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']")).click();
```

For click on Lock and Edit button use this code.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Lock & Edit']")).click();
```

Comment: I guess , you can put this in a comment rather than answer.

Comment: It's genuine answer, and why should i put this answer as `comment`. I know the valid answer. It's not the right way for down-voting @kishan